# Increase the font size in Firebug?

Tags: firebug, font-size

Is there a way to **increase the font-size** in the Firefox extension Firebug?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. Right click on the bug icon in the status bar.
2. Select "Open Firebug in New Window"
3. Select "View" > "Text Size" > "Increase Text Size"

The changes should stick if you revert back to opening Firebug in the same window.

**Update**

In new versions you can simply click on the bug icon in the code navigator and choose 'Text size'.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work on OS X, due to the lack of a "View" menu on the Firebug popup window. Prestaul's answer works, though, so there is hope!

Comment: this is outdated for 8.00.35, click the firebug icon

Answer (score 26):

Without opening Firebug in its own window, you can just click the bug icon in the top left of the Firebug pane and there is a "text size" option.

Comment: I. LOVE. YOU. Holy hell, I've been searching for a solution to this, but all I could find was tutorials and tips on how to use Firebug to tweak the font styles on your page, not Firebug itself. Stack Overflow saves the day again.

Comment: On Firebug 1.8, this doesn't work for the source code in the 'HTML' view, sadly.

Comment: Thanks for saving my eyes from the damage of small font size on a 1080P screen with 1920x1080 resolution. I hate programs that doesn't aware the custom (larger) DIP settings on Windows 7.

Comment: Yes this is the correct solution for modern firebug

Answer (score 8):

You increase the font-size in the Firefox extension Firebug as follows.

1. Open firebug by pressing F12.
2. Click on the bug icon of Firebug (The bug image at the left side of Firebug window plane.)
3. On clicking on the bug icon, a menu bar will open. In the menu bar, the "Text Size" option will be found.
4. Select the required Text Size from there.

Answer (score 5):

In Firebug 1.9.1 you can simply click on the bug icon in the code navigator and then choose 'Text size'.

Answer (score 5):

for mac that works for me

⌘ + Alt + Mousewheel

Answer (score 3):

Just click inside the FireBug window and use [Control][+] or [Control][-] key combinations.

With these hot-keys it's easier to work, since one can use them just as required.

You might say "that's not the font-size..." but the effect is quite the same, just on-the-fly.

Comment: On OSX (mac) the hot keys don't always work properly.  They increase/decrease the size of the viewed html page.  In addition, the [command][-] also decreases the size of the firebug view.  [command][+] did nothing, causing the firebug window to get smaller and smaller with no remedy other than the mouse/menu solution.  Kind of funny when you think about it.

Comment: Guess the key-mappings might be messed up on Mac version - or the focus is not set properly while key-input... on x86 this works all the time.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Increase Text Size for Firebug]

1. F12 to open FireBug
2. Click on the bug icon
3. Text Size--->Increase Text Size (**Ctrl** + **+**)

Answer (score 0):

Another way: You can edit the value for `extensions.firebug.textSize` in `about:config`. Setting the value to `0` resets the font size to the default.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl,Shift,+ and Ctrl,Shift,- to zoom firebug in and out.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.open firebug
2.on the right side there are three icons select open firebug in new window(option)
3.click left side firebug option on new window
4.mouse over to text size you find
  a.increase text size ctrl++
  b.decrease text size ctrl+-
  c.normal text size   ctrl+0
5.lastly right side there are three icons select open firebug in new window(option)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl + and Ctrl - It can be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be focus in firebug.

-Press **Ctrl** plus **- Key** to **decrease**.

-Press **Ctrl** plus **Shift** plus **+Key** to **increase**.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl + and Ctrl - will not work always.

Best option is as follows:
Open firebug by pressing F12.
Click on the bug icon of Firebug (The bug image at the left side of Firebug window plane.)
On clicking on the bug icon, a menu bar will open. In the menu bar, the "Text Size" option will be found.
Select the required Text Size from there.